# SpriteKit Refer to a Node that's Outside of a Function

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a game in SpriteKit that uses a functions to spawn a spike and I call that function every few seconds to spawn another spike. Here is that function

```
func summonSpike() {
            
            let spike = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spike")
            
            let randomizer = Int.random(in: 1..<2)
            
            // 1 = Left
            // 2 = Right
            
            if randomizer == 1 {
                
                spike.position = CGPoint(x: -70, y: 300)
                spike.zRotation = -1.5708
                
            } else {
                
                spike.position = CGPoint(x: 70, y: 300)
                spike.zRotation = 1.5708
                
            }
            
            spike.name = "spike"
            spike.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 60)
            spike.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spike"), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 60))
            spike.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            spike.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            
            if gameStarted == true && gameEnded == false {
                
                addChild(spike)
                
            }
                        
        }
```

I need to refer to each spike node that exists outside of the function. What's the best way to do this?, I tried putting the `let spike = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spike")` outside of the function but then it doesn't let me spawn multiple spikes. How do I refer to a node outside of the function?

Comment: let is how you declare constants in Swift….So, if you have one node use var sprite = … and then assign a sprite every time to that variable. If you want to track multiple sprites use array. var sprites:[SKSpriteNode] = [] and then add each node to an array after node is instantiated (or added to a scene).

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways to do this. as Whirlwind mentioned, you can save your sprites in an array. however i would recommend simply relying on the node structure itself as your storage. once you call `addChild(node)` you've effectively saved that node for later. here are two ways to access those nodes again, first by filtering on the node's class, and second by using the node's assigned name.

```
//get all child SKSpriteNodes by class
let nodes_by_class = self.children.compactMap({ $0 as? SKSpriteNode })

//get all children with a particular name 
let nodes_by_name = self.children.filter({ $0.name == "spike" })
```

you can also use `childNode(withName:)` to grab a single child based on name